# Troubleshooting problems with Viscosity and DNS requests

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

I'm using **Viscosity** 1.10.8 on macOS 14.2.1. A friend of mine has just sent to me the following OpenVPN configuration file for my client:

```
client
dev tun
remote <MY FRIEND'S IP> 1194 tcp
tun-mtu 1500
tls-client
nobind
ping 15
ping-restart 45
ping-timer-rem
mute-replay-warnings
verb 3
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
auth-user-pass
remote-cert-tls server
redirect-gateway def1
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
```

However, once connected I can't surf the internet at all. **Strangely enough, the same conf file works with the OpenVPN connect client**, so I'm not sure if this issue is strictly related to Viscosity or, more in general, to the OpenVPN settings.

Using `nslookup` in combination with `tcpdump`, I figured out that the problem is related to the DNS requests. If I start a capture and then I issue `nslookup www.google.it`, I get the following output:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -ni any port 53
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), snapshot length 524288 bytes
18:30:19.403577 IP 127.0.0.1.55553 > 127.0.0.1.53: 14064+ A? www.google.it. (31)
18:30:19.403591 IP 127.0.0.1.55553 > 127.0.0.1.53: 14064+ A? www.google.it. (31)
18:30:20.404482 IP6 ::1.50658 > ::1.53: 14064+ A? www.google.it. (31)
18:30:20.404503 IP6 ::1.50658 > ::1.53: 14064+ A? www.google.it. (31)
18:30:25.409492 IP 127.0.0.1.55553 > 127.0.0.1.53: 14064+ A? www.google.it. (31)
18:30:25.409523 IP 127.0.0.1.55553 > 127.0.0.1.53: 14064+ A? www.google.it. (31)
18:30:26.414496 IP6 ::1.50658 > ::1.53: 14064+ A? www.google.it. (31)
18:30:26.414531 IP6 ::1.50658 > ::1.53: 14064+ A? www.google.it. (31)
```

That makes no sense, since there's no DNS running on localhost. To complete the scenario here is the routing with active tunnel:

```
$ netstat -nr -f inet
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
0/1                192.168.10.1       UGScg              utun10
default            192.168.1.1        UGScg                 en5
default            192.168.10.1       UGScIg             utun10
<FRIEND'S IP>/32   192.168.1.1        UGSc                  en5
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                    lo0
128.0/1            192.168.10.1       UGSc               utun10
169.254            link#13            UCS                   en5      !
192.168.1          link#13            UCS                   en5      !
192.168.1.1/32     link#13            UCS                   en5      !
192.168.1.1        10:71:b3:94:ce:70  UHLWIir               en5   1199
192.168.1.100/32   link#13            UCS                   en5      !
192.168.1.100      0:e0:4c:68:0:40    UHLWI                 lo0
192.168.10         192.168.10.42      UGSc               utun10
192.168.10.1/32    link#24            UCS                utun10
192.168.10.1       link#24            UHWIir             utun10
192.168.10.42      192.168.10.42      UH                 utun10
224.0.0/4          link#13            UmCS                  en5      !
224.0.0/4          link#24            UmCSI              utun10
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI                en5
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI                en5
239.255.255.250    link#24            UHmW3I             utun10   2400
255.255.255.255/32 link#13            UCS                   en5      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#24            UCSI               utun10
```

Finally, here's the log from Viscosity upon connection:

```
Opened utun device utun10
/sbin/ifconfig utun10 delete
NOTE: Tried to delete pre-existing tun/tap instance -- No Problem if failure
/sbin/ifconfig utun10 192.168.10.42 192.168.10.42 netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500 up
/sbin/route add -net 192.168.10.0 192.168.10.42 255.255.255.0
/sbin/route add -net <MY FRIEND'S IP> 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 192.168.10.1 128.0.0.0
/sbin/route add -net 128.0.0.0 192.168.10.1 128.0.0.0
Initialization Sequence Completed
DNS mode set to Full
State changed to Connected
```

As a temporary workaround for Viscosity, I'm setting [DNS mode](https://www.sparklabs.com/support/kb/article/configuring-dns-and-wins-settings/#dns-modes) to Split DNS, and DNS works via my local resolver. I've been using Viscosity with OpenVPN for years without problems just importing *.ovpn files. Also in this case, I'd like to find a way to avoid such a manual workaround. Do I need to tell my friend that she should change something on her server side? Or can I fix just modifying the client.ovpn file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, it turned out that it was a problem of the DNS configuration of the VPN server.